# Splited response when receiving data packet with CPort Lib on Delphi Berlin 10.1

Tags: delphi, serial-port, usb, packet, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a device connected to the USB port, when I send the request I receive a response. But I am receiving a splited response, looks like the CPort is not waiting for the whole response.

```
Sent: getNodeStatus,03
(HEX) > A5 FE 03 10 00 10 19 17 00 1A 17 16 17 10 19 00 19 19 19 00 10 19 10 10 10 00 19 00 10 10 00 19      
(HEX) > 17 19 00 00 10 10 10 10 18 10 10 19 19 10 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 6D
```

I would like to get both lines merged into one with the same response:

```
Sent: getNodeStatus,03
(HEX) > A5 FE 03 10 00 10 19 17 00 1A 17 16 17 10 19 00 19 19 19 00 10 19 10 10 10 00 19 00 10 10 00 19 17 19 00 00 10 10 10 10 18 10 10 19 19 10 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 6D
```

I don't know how to achieve that, this is `OnPacket` code:

```
procedure TForm1.ComDataPacket1Packet(Sender: TObject; const Str: string);
var
  I:Integer;
  t:byte;
  str2:String;
begin
    for I:=1 to length(str) do
      begin
        str2 := str2+IntToHex(Byte(str[I]),2)+' ';
      end;
    memo1.lines.add('(HEX) > '+str2);
    memo1.lines.add(' ');
end;
```

One important thing to keep in mind, is not possible to use the `StartString & StotString` property of the `ComDataPacket` since it changes anytime. Any other idea?

Extra info:

When I use another request that give me a shortest response, it does not come splited

```
Sent: getId,03
(HEX) > A5 81 52 CS
```

Comment: Why do StartString and StopString (I assume you made a typo) change? If the response is split, and the data doesn't have something to identify the total length, or something to indicate that it's at the end, I'd say you're screwed, because your app won't know when it has a complete packet. Otherwise, you could use a variable outside of the scope of ComDataPacket1Packet and simply concatenate it until a full packet is received

Comment: Concatenate the variable is what I don't want to do, I should preffer a single response.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with CPort.. is there a BufferSize property or similar? Otherwise, it might be a case of changing the source.

Comment: Yes, it comes with a `Buffer` property with 2 subproperties which are `InputSize & OutputSize` both are 1024 I increased them to 2048 and still the same issue

Comment: It seems you don't know message length, start and stop character. The only possible way then, is to time the incoming bytes. When a gap is detected, you know you have a complete string. I can't say if the packet handler can be setup with those conditions though.

Comment: What is the actual byte layout of the messages? I find it very hard to believe that a ComPort-based protocol would not frame its messages in a deterministic manner. I've dealt with many Comport devices over the years, and they have ALWAYS framed their messages one way or another, either with start/end bytes, length prefixes, or fixed-sized messages. For instance, in your example, `A5` looks like a possible message start delimiter. What about `6D` and `C5`? A checksum, maybe? I'm guessing the messages you have shown are not as variable-length as you think they are.

Comment: Yes Remy, allways start with A5, and end up in a checksum, but I don't know how to calculate that checksum. I am pretty new handling USB connected devices

Comment: Ok, `checksum = byte0+byte1+...+byte52` but I am still not don't know the final checkseum because it gets splited before calculate it

Answer (score 0):

> CPort is not waiting for the whole response.

That is expected behaviour on any serial port, including USB ones. You will have to manually merge the data.

Note that the data is highly likely already split when transferred over USB - CPort usually follows USB transactions very closely.

In case your protocol does not allow to determine message end, you will have to work with a timeout for example.

Comment: Was playing with the timeout sub properties: `ReadInterval, ReadTotalMultiplier & ReadTotalConstant` but the response is the same, any idea of how to use these properties?

Comment: These may not work properly on USB2Serial ports, but YMMV.